# Python Json parser

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that has the following structure:-

```
{
    "contributors": null, 
    "truncated": false, 
    "text": "@HomeShop18 #DreamJob to professional rafter", 
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
    "id": 421584490452893696, 
    "favorite_count": 0, 
    "source": "<a href=\"https://mobile.twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Mobile Web (M2)</a>", 
    "retweeted": false, 
    "coordinates": null, 
    "entities": {
        "symbols": [], 
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "id": 183093247, 
                "indices": [
                    0, 
                    11
                ], 
                "id_str": "183093247", 
                "screen_name": "HomeShop18", 
                "name": "HomeShop18"
            }
        ], 
        "hashtags": [
            {
                "indices": [
                    12, 
                    21
                ], 
                "text": "DreamJob"
            }
        ], 
        "urls": []
    }, 
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": "HomeShop18", 
    "id_str": "421584490452893696", 
    "retweet_count": 0, 
    "in_reply_to_user_id": 183093247, 
    "favorited": false, 
    "user": {
        "follow_request_sent": null, 
        "profile_use_background_image": true, 
        "default_profile_image": false, 
        "id": 2254546045, 
        "verified": false, 
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413952088880594944/rcdr59OY_normal.jpeg", 
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "171106", 
        "profile_text_color": "8A7302", 
        "followers_count": 87, 
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "BCB302", 
        "id_str": "2254546045", 
        "profile_background_color": "0F0A02", 
        "listed_count": 1, 
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "utc_offset": null, 
        "statuses_count": 9793, 
        "description": "Rafter. Rafting is what I do. Me aur mera Tablet.  Technocrat of Future", 
        "friends_count": 231, 
        "location": "", 
        "profile_link_color": "473623", 
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/413952088880594944/rcdr59OY_normal.jpeg", 
        "following": null, 
        "geo_enabled": false, 
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2254546045/1388065343", 
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "name": "Jayy", 
        "lang": "en", 
        "profile_background_tile": false, 
        "favourites_count": 41, 
        "screen_name": "JzayyPsingh", 
        "notifications": null, 
        "url": null, 
        "created_at": "Fri Dec 20 05:46:00 +0000 2013", 
        "contributors_enabled": false, 
        "time_zone": null, 
        "protected": false, 
        "default_profile": false, 
        "is_translator": false
    }, 
    "geo": null, 
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "183093247", 
    "lang": "en", 
    "created_at": "Fri Jan 10 10:09:09 +0000 2014", 
    "filter_level": "medium", 
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
    "place": null
}
```

The file has almost 1500 such dictionaries in it. I want to know if there is any preexisting parser, in python, for such a file, for lazy parsing. I want said parser to return only one dictionary at a time, or, worst case, return line by line data. What should I do?

Comment: In this case, a line means a dict object right?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, yes, am editing my question to read correctly.

Comment: what about http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html ?

Comment: You know that the example JSON you have shown is invalid, right?

Comment: @greole, I don't see any function there for this exact parsing..am a newbie, so am probably being blind.

Comment: @thefourtheye, yes, that is just a sample. The actual is rather long. Should I post it?

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh Nope. Its not about the size. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a **workaround** function using [json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode). I wish someone suggested a better way to handle this problem.

```
import json
import re

nonspace = re.compile(r'\S')
def iterparse(j):
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    pos = 0
    while True:
        matched = nonspace.search(j, pos)
        if not matched:
            break
        pos = matched.start()
        decoded, pos = decoder.raw_decode(j, pos)
        yield decoded
```

Example usage:

```
>>> j = '''
... { "id": 1 }
... { "id": 2 }
... '''
>>> list(iterparse(j))
[{u'id': 1}, {u'id': 2}]
```

Comment: is your use of matched = nonspace.search(j, pos) correct? I mean, there is no target string, as per syntax here..http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh, What do you mean for target string?

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh, `j` is json string (haystack), `nonspace` is a needle (any non space character). Am I clear?

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh, You're seeing wrong function. I used [`re.RegexObject.search` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search), not `re.search` function. It slightly different.

Comment: on executing this, i am getting this traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 16, in <module>
    list (iterparse(s))
  File "new.py", line 10, in iterparse
    matched = nonspace.search(j, pos)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh, What do you pass to the function? file object? I assumed you pass string object.

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh, Pass the file content. `list(iterparse(file_obj.read()))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `raw_decode` from `json.JSONDecoder` to do it without reading the whole file into memory:

> raw_decode(s)
>   Decode a JSON document from s (a str beginning with a JSON document) and return a 2-tuple of the Python representation and the index in s where the document ended.
>
> This can be used to decode a JSON document from a string that may have extraneous data at the end.

```
import json

def iterparse(file_obj):
    decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
    buf = ""
    for line in file_obj:
        buf += line.strip()
        try:
            res = decoder.raw_decode(buf)
            buf = ""
            yield res[0]
        except ValueError:
            pass

with open("stuff.json") as f:
    for obj in iterparse(f):
        print obj
```

Comment: somehow, I don't really understand how, this code gives the first dictionary perfectly. However, the other dictionaries are not obtained by this

Comment: @ApoorvAshutosh -- When I tested it on multiple of your example objects it works correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Try [ijson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson/) parser:

Example usage:

```
import ijson

parser = ijson.parse(urlopen('url/'))
stream.write('<geo>')
for prefix, event, value in parser:
    if (prefix, event) == ('earth', 'map_key'):
        stream.write('<%s>' % value)
        continent = value
    elif prefix.endswith('.name'):
        stream.write('<object name="%s"/>' % value)
    elif (prefix, event) == ('earth.%s' % continent, 'end_map'):
        stream.write('</%s>' % continent)
stream.write('</geo>')
```