# print keys from a file of multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to print keys from a file of multiple dictionaries

I want to make it so that it only prints the items of a certain key.
The file contains several dictionaries.

Comment: `json.load` and `json.loads` does not decode multiple json object, example: `json.loads('{}{}')` shows `Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`, view: [python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data)

Comment: Can you show us how your input file is structured? Is it one line per dictionary? If that's the case you need to use readline (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) combined with a loop and append the dicts to a list of dicts, then iterate through the list to print the keys.