# Get keys in list/dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, list

I have a list/dictionary which I'm trying to get the keys from.

Where I'm trying to print the keys is the `get_keys()` function, which is the part that needs fixing.

```
import json, io
business_json = "business.json"

def read_json(file):
    lines = [line for line in open(file)]
    js = [json.loads(line) for line in lines]
    for item in js:
        name = item.get("name")
    return js

def get_keys(data):
    for key in data.keys():
        print(key)

def get_values_for_category(data, category):
    values = []
    for item in data:
        values.append(item.get(category))
    return values

def main():
    json_data = read_json(business_json) #works
    names = get_values_for_category(json_data, "name") #works 
    get_keys(json_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get with above's `get_keys(data)` is:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

If I instead try:

```
for key, val in data.items():
    print(key, val)
```

or

`for key in list(data).keys()` or `for key in list(data.keys())` I get same issue.

So, I have a list and need the keys.  However, all the ways I've found to get a lists' keys returns an error.

Is it an issue with how I'm getting `js` in the `read_json()` function?  I'm confused as to why I can use a key (`"name"`) to get values, but can't return the various keys I can look up...

**EDIT**: Full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Batman\Documents\- Datasets\yelp_dataset\dataset\Yelp_analysis.py", line 29, in <module>
        main()<br>
    File "D:\Batman\Documents\- Datasets\yelp_dataset\dataset\Yelp_analysis.py", line 25, in main
        get_keys(json_data)<br>
    File "D:\Batman\Documents\- Datasets\yelp_dataset\dataset\Yelp_analysis.py", line 13, in get_keys
        for key in data.keys():<br> 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

(FWIW a summary of the .json file is [here](https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/json) and a snippet of the data is [here on PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/p8Bgs4uS)).

Comment: Do you have a list or a directory? They are very different things. Obviously the error says lists do not have keys, so you want a dictionary there

Comment: Can I see the whole traceback?

Comment: @cricket_007 - I thought I had a dictionary, using `type(js)` I get `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @cricket_007 You said "**They are beryl different things**"

Comment: Stupid autocorrect ;) `type(data)` in the get keys function is a list

Comment: @BryanZeng - See edit.  A note (which may be material) is that I really just want to import json data and use it as such. I get an error ([related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626952)) that I found a way around, but perhaps that's an issue...

Comment: @BruceWayne What is your python version? I tried in 3.6.2 and it gave me another error

Comment: @BryanZeng - I have 3.6.2

Comment: @BruceWayne Please indent the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would read the file.

```
def read_json(file):
    return [json.loads(line) for line in open(file)]
```

I've seen this Dataset be asked about multiple times, and you might want to checkout the `ijson` library to read large JSON files. Also, I personally think those Yelp files are meant to be ran through Hadoop / Spark processes.

Anyway, now that is a list of JSON objects, which themselves have keys, not the list itself.

If you're going to do this

```
json_data = read_json(business_json)
get_keys(json_data)
```

Then the get keys function should look like so

```
def get_keys(data):
    for obj in data:
        print(obj.keys())
```

Comment: Ooh! That `read_json()` works well!  When I do the `get_keys()` you show, it's correctly showing the keys (yay!) but it's doing it for *every object* which is thousands of rows. ...how can I just show it once? I tried `for obj in data[0]: print(obj.keys())` but get `AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'.

Comment: `print(data[0].keys())`...no looping

Comment: Ah, duh! Thanks!!  I'll look in to ljson too :D