# normally my api returns json, but sometimes returns a full response object?

Tags: python, json

All,

I have a script i have in place which fetches JSON off of a webserver.  Simple as the following:

```
url = "foo.com/json"
response = requests.get(url).content
data = json.loads(response)
```

but i noticed is that sometimes instead of returning the JSON object, it will return what looks like a response dump.  See here: https://pastebin.com/fUy5YMuY

What confuses me is to how to continue on.

Right now i took the above python and wrapped it

```
try:
    url = "foo.com/json"
    response = requests.get(url).content
    data = json.loads(response)
except Exception as ex:
    with open("test.txt", "w") as t:
        t.write(response)
    print("Error", sys.exc_info())
```

Is there a way to catch this?  Right now I get a ValueError...   and then reparse it?  I was thinking to do something like:

```
except Exception as ex:
    response = reparse(response)
```

but im still confused as to why it will sometimes return the JSON and other times, the header info + content.

```
def reparse(response):
    """
    Catch the ValueError and attempt to reparse it for the json contnet
    """
```

Can i feed something like the pastebin dump into some sort of requests.Reponse class or similar?

*Edit* Here is the full stack trace I am getting.

```
File "scrape_people_by_fcc_docket.py", line 82, in main
    json_data = get_page(limit, page*limit)
File "scrape_people_by_fcc_docket.py", line 13, in get_page
    data = json.loads(response)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 16 column 367717 (char 3 - 368222)
 None
```

In the above code, the `response` variable is defined by:

```
response = requests.get(url).content
```

which is odd because most of the time, reponse will return a JSON object which is completely parsable.

Ideally, I have been trying to find a way to, when content isnt JSON, pass some how parse it for the actual content and then continue on.

Comment: The pastebin image is really does not look like a request dump. It is a reasonable response from an API.

Comment: When you do json.loads value error comes? If so then post full traceback

Comment: @ArpitSolanki usually it is just returning me JSON to manipulate.   When I hit this Error it says:  *Value Error, Extra data line A column A - ling B column B*.  

The differences I have noticed was that `x.content` would return pure JSON and now it returns the header data as well.  Which is unusual..    It returns the error similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data but instead it points to my `json.loads()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `.text` or `.content` you can use the response method: `.json()` which so far seems to resolve my issues.  I am doing continual testing and watching for errors and will update this as needed, but it seems that the json function will return the data i need without headers, and similarly already calls `json.loads` or similar to parse the information.