# How to read a json file with more than one records

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save high scores for a game and also load it in high score section, but the way I am saving adds more than one record to the JSON file. The problem is while loading, I get the error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data` only when there is more than one record.

I am pretty sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140858/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-extra-data-line-2-column-1-char-190) is my problem but me being a starter I cannot make sense out of it.

what I am saving

```
score = {
    "score" : round_counter,
    "name" : player["name"],
    "hp left" : player["hitpoints"]
}
```

how I am saving it

```
if os.path.isfile('score.json'):
        print("your score has been added")
        json_dump = json.dumps(score)
        f = open("score.json","a")
        f.write(json_dump)
        f.close()  

else :
        print ("database doesn't exist so it was created!")
        json_dump = json.dumps(score)
        f = open("score.json","x")
        f.write(json_dump)
        f.close()
```

how I am reading it

```
with open ("score.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print(data)
```

It works for the first run but when there are 2 records in .json file I cannot read it. I don't know if I need more complete reading code or the way I am saving multiple dictionaries in .json is in its root wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to store more than one JSON record, use an array, as when loading you can just load JSON types (an an array is the ideal JSON type you're looking for for that use case).

In that case, to read all scores:

```py
scores = []
with open ("score.json") as json_data:
    scores = json.load(json_data)
```

But most important, to write them to a file:

```py
scores.append(score)
json_dump = json.dumps(scores)
f = open("score.json","w")
f.write(json_dump)
f.close()
```

**Update**
The last code can also be written using `json.dump`:

```py
scores.append(score)
f = open("score.json","w")
json.dump(scores, f)
f.write(json_dump)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is written, it will append score dictionaries instead of adding an object in an array of scores.

If you check the output file score.json it will look like {...}{...}{...} whereas it should be like [{...},{...},{...}]

Answer (score -1):

You can read the file line by line, every line will contain a valid JSON object:

```
with open('score.json') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        data = json.loads(line)
        # do something with data
```

Or if you need everything in one object:

```
with open('score.json') as fp:
    data = []
    for line in fp:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: "You can read the file line by line, every line will contain a valid JSON object:" => well, no necessarily...

Comment: It is true as long as you don't alter the `indent` parameter of `json.dumps()`.