# JSONDecoderError: Extra data

Tags: json

```
{
   "backend_port":6712,
   "website_port":5000,
   "secret_key":"MY_PRECIOUS_SECRET_KEY",
   "salt":"MY_TABLE_SALT",
   "ssl":false,
   "ssl_cert":"/home/andres/.mycroft/personal_backend/certs/MycroftPersonalServer.crt",
   "ssl_key":"/home/andres/.mycroft/personal_backend/certs/MycroftPersonalServer.key",
   "mail_user":"xxx@gmail.com",
   "mail_password":"xxx",
   "mail_server":"smtp.googlemail.com",
   "mail_port":465
}{
   "stt":{
        "module":"google",
        "google":{

        }
   }
}
```

I get this response:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 429 (char 428)
```

Comment: It's *not* JSON. You can't just mash two objects together like that, there has to be a single root.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, now i understand all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140858/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-extra-data-line-2-column-1-char-190)