# How to remove the JSON Loads Error at Server Side?

Tags: json, python-3.x, multithreading, pickle, jsonpickle

I am trying to send a dictionary over Ethernet connect from my client computer to server computer.
The dictionary looks like this:

```
data_transfer_dict={'Target':'', 'Mission':'', 'Optical/IR':'',
 'Arm':'', 'Optical Zoom':0, 'Digital Zoom':0, 'Pitch':00000,
 'Yaw':00000, 'Reset Camera':0, 'Target Selection':0, 'Take Screenshot':0}
```

The method I have tried is json as well as pickle
**JSON Code:**
*Client Side*

```
obj1.send_data(json.dumps(data_transfer_dict).encode('utf-8'))
def data send(self, data):
    if self.is_running:
        self.client_socket.send(data)
```

*Server Side*

```
while True:
    count_bytes=self.client_socket.recv(2048)
    count=json.loads(count_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
    print("Dictionary: ", count)
```

The above code snippet is referenced from [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-interconversion-between-dictionary-and-bytes/#:~:text=Method%20%3A%20Using%20encode()%20%2B%20dumps,then%20to%20corresponding%20byte%20value](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-interconversion-between-dictionary-and-bytes/#:%7E:text=Method%20%3A%20Using%20encode()%20%2B%20dumps,then%20to%20corresponding%20byte%20value).
The client send the data continuously in a multi thread and the server receive that data continuously.
The error produced at the server side is: **json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 193 (char 192)**

I have also referred to these page but could understand much and get help:
[Python json.loads shows ValueError: Extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data)
[json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 190)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140858/json-decoder-jsondecodeerror-extra-data-line-2-column-1-char-190)

Comment: Can you try validating your data if it is in 'json format' before sending or receiving data. You can validate it through free online services.
See if that helps.

Comment: I have tried it just now and it says JSON is valid. I seems as if it is unable to decode at server side while it receives the data continuously.