# Json , scrape into web page - python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, web-scraping

i am scraping into certain webpage using requests and beautifulsoup libs in python

so i got the element that i want in this simple code

```
<script>
data = {'user':{'id':1,'name':'joe','age':18,'email':'joe@hotmail.com'}}
</script>
```

so i want to get the email value in variable 
but the whole element comes back into list and when i specify the text of that tag 
i can't get it into json it gives me errors in the columns 
so any idea ?
i'll appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple, maybe will help you.

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<script>
data = {'user':{'id':1,'name':'joe','age':18,'email':'joe@hotmail.com'}}
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
# slices [7:] mean that we ignore the `data = `
# and replace the single quotes to double quotes for json.loads()
json_data = json.loads(soup.find('script').text.strip()[7:].replace("'", '"'))
print(json_data)
print(type(json_data))
```

**Output**

```
{'user': {'id': 1, 'name': 'joe', 'age': 18, 'email': 'joe@hotmail.com'}}
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: u r getting close enough from what i want , and i also did this and gives me error in columns 




`code`
  json_data = json.loads(soup.find_all('script')[3].text.strip()[21:])
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\TOSHIBA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3548 (char 3547)

Comment: can you show the `script` tag that you want to scrape ?

Comment: am not sure if i can do it here because it's too long

Comment: this may help you, i think you have many `dict` objects, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data

Comment: actually i want to get the csrf_token value 
here [CSRF-TOKEN](https://prnt.sc/k2ki8i)

Comment: That's probably because of the `;` at the end. Use something like `[7:-1]` instead of `[7:]`. Also, slightly more reliable than using such magic numbers is to get everything between the first `{` and the last `}` in the script tag content and parse it as JSON.

Comment: @UltraInstinct you are right! i check it and put a `;` at the end and it return the same error `Extra data: line 1 column 66 (char 65)`

Comment: @UltraInstinct u  r right ,
Thank u guys now it accepted as a json data 
but now i can't call the csrf_token from json or maybe i forgot the right code 
DrutaRuslan Man i appreciate ur help very well thanks <3