# Python not printing JSON file contents

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to load a json file that I have but i keep getting en error saying :

```
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 27 column 1 (char 48 - 1512)
```

My code is as follows :

```
def main():
    with open('statement.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    print (data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

JSON file is as follows:

```
{"File Size": "16281", "File Name": "apple.json"}
{"File Size": "128706", "File Name": "banana.json"}
{"File Size": "47366083", "File Name": "carrot.json"}
{"File Size": "7484", "File Name": "pear.json"}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data).

Comment: You should include the contents of the json file in your question

Comment: added contents of json file @Sam

Answer (score 1):

Input is not a valid JSON object, but [newline-delimited JSON](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec).

You should use :

```py
with open('statement.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
        print (data)
```

to print each JSON document (each line).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is wrong. You have multiple JSON objects in one file. You need to put them all into a list.

You could have a top level list like this.

```
[
    {"File Size": "16281", "File Name": "apple.json"},
    {"File Size": "128706", "File Name": "banana.json"},
    {"File Size": "47366083", "File Name": "carrot.json"},
    {"File Size": "7484", "File Name": "pear.json"}
]
```

or create a whole new object and put the list inside, something like this

```
{
    "file_list":[
        {"File Size": "16281", "File Name": "apple.json"},
        {"File Size": "128706", "File Name": "banana.json"},
        {"File Size": "47366083", "File Name": "carrot.json"},
        {"File Size": "7484", "File Name": "pear.json"}
    ]
}
```