# How to resolve an error message when attempting to start Jupyter-Notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter-lab

I have Jupyter-Notebook on an AWS EC2 instance. It was working fine until I made a few changes/updates and now I'm getting the following error message when I attempt to use Jupyter-Notebook:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-5:~$ jupyter-notebook 
[E 06:41:09.375 NotebookApp] Exception while loading config file /home/ubuntu/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 562, in _load_config_files
    config = loader.load_config()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/loader.py", line 406, in load_config
    dct = self._read_file_as_dict()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/loader.py", line 412, in _read_file_as_dict
    return json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 17 column 1 - line 18 column 1 (char 255 - 257)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1633, in initialize
    self.init_server_extensions()



 File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1559, in init_server_extensions
    section = manager.get(self.config_file_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/services/config/manager.py", line 25, in get
    recursive_update(config, cm.get(section_name))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/config_manager.py", line 103, in get
    recursive_update(data, json.load(f))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 17 column 1 - line 18 column 1 (char 255 - 257)
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: This JSON config file (`jupyter_notebook_config.json`) seems to be broken. If you can, you should try to open it and see what's on lines 17 and 18 (as the error message indicates). Otherwise, try to downgrade to bring Jupyter to a previous state.

Comment: The explanation of this error (but not in the context of Jupyter): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data