# JSON load function gives Extra Data value error

Tags: python, json

When I read JSON file it gives me following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 16043 column 2 (char 370886)
```

This error seems to be valid as `json.load` does not decode multiple json objects and my JSON contains 2 or more objects.

```
{ "log": [ 
 {
   "code": "info",
   "message": {"text": "[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule "},
   "refs": [{"href": "xule"}],
   "level": "info"
 }
,
{
   "code": "xyz.F1.all.7",
   "level": "error",
   "message": {
                "text": "[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114",
                "severity": "error",
                "cid": "63096080",
                "filing_url": "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd"
             },
   "refs": [{"href": "xule"}]      

}]
}
{ "log": [ 
 {
   "code": "info",
   "message": {"text": "[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule "},
   "refs": [{"href": "xule"}],
   "level": "info"
 }
,
{
   "code": "xyz.F1.all.7",
   "level": "error",
   "message": {
                "text": "[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114",
                "severity": "error",
                "cid": "63096080",
                "filing_url": "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd"
             },
   "refs": [{"href": "xule"}]


}]}
```

I came across this article for resolution: [Python json.loads shows ValueError: Extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data)
which says I need to add my log dictionaries in `json.dumps()` prior to `json.loads()`. But, I am unable to get it done. Please can anyone help me.

This is my python code:

```
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/logfile.json', encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to jsonlint:

```
Error: Parse error on line 27:
...le"          }]      }   ]} {    "log": [{           "cod
------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

In other words , you have 2 jsons in one, should be a list, as in

```
[{
        "log": [{
                "code": "info",
                "message": {
                    "text": "[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule "
                },
                "refs": [{
                    "href": "xule"
                }],
                "level": "info"
            },
            {
                "code": "xyz.F1.all.7",
                "level": "error",
                "message": {
                    "text": "[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114",
                    "severity": "error",
                    "cid": "63096080",
                    "filing_url": "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd"
                },
                "refs": [{
                    "href": "xule"
                }]

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "log": [{
                "code": "info",
                "message": {
                    "text": "[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule "
                },
                "refs": [{
                    "href": "xule"
                }],
                "level": "info"
            },
            {
                "code": "xyz.F1.all.7",
                "level": "error",
                "message": {
                    "text": "[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114",
                    "severity": "error",
                    "cid": "63096080",
                    "filing_url": "C:\\Users\\TEST\\Desktop\\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd"
                },
                "refs": [{
                    "href": "xule"
                }]


            }
        ]
    }
]
```

TRY SOMETHING LikE:

```
import json

mylist = []
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/logfile.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    new_el = ''
    for l in f:
       new_el += l.rstrip('\n')
       try:
          sub = json.loads(new_el)
          mylist.append(sub)
          new_el = ''
       except:# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
          pass
print(mylist)
```

This prints:
[{u'log': [{u'message': {u'text': u'[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule '}, u'code': u'info', u'refs': [{u'href': u'xule'}], u'level': u'info'}, {u'message': {u'text': u'[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114', u'filing_url': u'C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd', u'severity': u'error', u'cid': u'63096080'}, u'code': u'xyz.F1.all.7', u'refs': [{u'href': u'xule'}], u'level': u'error'}]}, {u'log': [{u'message': {u'text': u'[info] Activation of plug-in abcd rule processor (xule) successful, version Check version using Tools->Xule->Version on the GUI or --xule-version on the command line. - xule '}, u'code': u'info', u'refs': [{u'href': u'xule'}], u'level': u'info'}, {u'message': {u'text': u'[xyz.F1.all.7] The value for ForResale with a value of 63 has a unit of utr:MWh. This concept allows units of utr:MWh.\n\nElement : xyz:ForResale\nPeriod : 2016-01-01 to 2016-12-31\nUnit : utr:MWh\n\nRule Id:xyz.F1.all.7 - TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd 4114', u'filing_url': u'C:\Users\TEST\Desktop\TestUtilitiesInc-428-2016Q4F1.abcd', u'severity': u'error', u'cid': u'63096080'}, u'code': u'xyz.F1.all.7', u'refs': [{u'href': u'xule'}], u'level': u'error'}]}]

Comment: For testing purpose I gave only two logs. But my actual file has 60K logs for which I need to parse the file using python.

Comment: well you need to make them into a list, try turning them into a dict somehow, but your problem is pbbly you just printed them and are trying to load them as if they were a json and they are not a valid json, just a bunch of jsons dumped in the same file

Comment: you owe me a beer

Comment: Thanks you so much :)