# How to save and load data from JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

How can I load data from JSON file with raw long text data?

I have big file with news:

[image]

`[body]` is a news data that I need to analyze.

I tried to read it like this:

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as openfile: 
  
    # Reading from json file 
    dfnew = json.load(openfile) 
openfile.close
```

But I get an error:

```
Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1938)
```

Maybe you know the better way, how can I save it, to easily read?

I created the file from dataframe by using this code:

```
df.to_json('file.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python json.loads shows ValueError: Extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data)

Comment: You are having data in the *JSON Lines* format. You just have to decode every line on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be in the *Newline Delimited JSON* format. Instead of trying to parse the whole file, you can parse the individual lines with `json.loads`. Also you don't need to close files if you are using a `with` statement.

```
import json

with open('file.json') as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        dfnew = json.loads(line)
        print(dfnew)
```