# Reading a JSON file using Python - JSONDecodeError Extra Data

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm following along with https://realpython.com/python-json/.  I'm using Python 3.8, on a Windows 10 machine, using IDLE.

I deviated a bit from the example.

```
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> data1 = {
    'president': {
        'name': 'dumb-bell beetlebox',
        'species': 'betelgusian'
    }
}
>>> data2 = {
    'emperor': {
        'name': 'Ezekiel Wheel',
        'species': 'klingon'
    }
}
>>> data3 = {
    'king': {
        'name': 'tech shiny',
        'species': 'two hundred'
    }
}
>>>
>>> with open('data1_file.json', 'w') as wf:
    json.dump(data1, wf)
>>> with open('data1_file.json', 'a') as af:
    af.write('\n')
    json.dump(data2, af)
    af.write('\n')
    json.dump(data3, af)

    
1
1
```

This created the json file, with the data per line.

I then tried to read it.

```
>>> with open('data1_file.json', 'r') as rf:
    data = json.load(rf)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#139>", line 2, in <module>
    data4 = json.load(rf)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 73)
```

On the advice from a friend, who said there may have been extraneous data in the file -

```
>>> print(repr(open('data1_file.json').read()))
'{"president": {"name": "dumb-bell beetlebox", "species": "betelgusian"}}\n{"emperor": {"name": "Ezekiel Wheel", "species": "klingon"}}\n{"king": {"name": "tech shiny", "species": "two hundred"}}'
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `json.load` does not decode multiple json objects. You'll probably want to place the data in an array. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data) for more info