# Python json.load JSONDecodeError: Extra data error when trying load multiple json dictionaries

Tags: python, json, jsondecoder

So I have to import a json file in an identical format shown below:

```
{
    "name": "bob"
}
{
    "name": "sarah"
}
```

This is the function I am trying to use to open it:

```
def read_json_file(file):
    with open(file, "r") as r:
        response = json.load(r)
        return response
```

I am getting this error when trying to load it:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 4 column 1 (char 22)

There's no way for me to fix the json data as the file is quite large. I need a way to work around it to parse through each dictionary.

I have already tried the method when this question was asked:

[Python json.loads shows ValueError: Extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data)

I tried changing my function to match the top answer:

```
    response = json.dumps(r)
```

That however brought upon this error:

> TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable

Any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: The example you've given is not valid JSON

Comment: @DarkKnight I know that but this is the format I've received it in and the file is too large to correct it so I need a workaround for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order solving that kind of "multiple"/"invalid" JSON, you can read the entire file, add these brackets `[]` to encapsulate the string and then load it as string with `json.loads()`.

1. Read whole file as string, store it into a variable.
2. Remove all occurrences of newlines and spaces.
3. Add the comma `,` the intersection `}{`, so it will be `...},{...`.
4. Encapsulate it with the brackets `[]`.
5. Use `json.loads()` to parse the JSON string.

Full code:

```
def read_json_file(file):
    with open(file, "r") as r:
        response = r.read()
        response = response.replace('\n', '')
        response = response.replace('}{', '},{')
        response = "[" + response + "]"
        return json.loads(response)
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I insert this function

`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 3)`

Comment: Sorry, I did not watch clearly that each brackets are placed in a single line. Have edited my answer

Comment: I'm not sure that replacing all spaces is a good idea. Consider {'name': 'John Smith'}

Comment: That works! I removed replacing spaces as that would not be the output I'm looking for but the rest of the function works

Comment: @DarkKnight Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @python_help Thanks for the suggestions. I have edited my answer. Please also kindly upvote and accept my answer if you find it solves your problem/helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JSONDecoder.raw_decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) to incrementally consume the input. Here's an example based on the [source of decode()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2cdbd3b8b2bb4fa0dbcc04ce305fbafaeedd9e67/Lib/json/decoder.py#L332):

```
def json_decode_many(s):
  import json
  import json.decoder
  decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
  _w = json.decoder.WHITESPACE.match

  idx = 0

  while True:
    idx = _w(s, idx).end() # skip leading whitespace
    if idx >= len(s):
      break
    obj, idx = decoder.raw_decode(s, idx=idx)
    yield obj
```

Then usage looks like

```
>>> input_string = """
{
  "name": "bob"
}
{
  "name": "sarah"
}
"""
>>> for x in json_decode_many(input_string):
...   print("Decoded:", x)
...
Decoded: {'name': 'bob'}
Decoded: {'name': 'sarah'}
```

Comment: while this is rather verbose, this should be the accepted solution