# json load fails for nested json in kinesis firehose stream

Tags: python, json, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to stream cloudwatch metric using kinesis firehose to S3. I am using Lambda python function to manipulate data. My major issue is the nested payload json is failing when I am trying json.load. I have tried multiple way to achieve it but not able to. Pasting below all the debug outputs

```
import base64
import json

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []

    for record in event['records']:
        print(record['recordId'])
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        payload_obj = json.loads(payload)
        # Do custom processing on the payload here
        payload_obj['event_timestamp'] = int(payload_obj['timestamp'] / 1000)
        print(payload_obj)
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(payload_obj, default=str).encode('utf-8')).decode("utf-8")
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))

    return {'records': output}
```

Error is:

```
[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 373)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 13, in lambda_handler
    payload_obj = json.loads(payload)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
```

Payload is:

[image]

Each payload is as below

Record 1:

```
{
    "metric_stream_name": "timestamp-day-partition-parquet",
    "account_id": "123456",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "namespace": "AWS/RDS",
    "metric_name": "ForwardingMasterOpenSessions",
    "dimensions": {
        "DBClusterIdentifier": "aurora-mysql-testbox",
        "Role": "WRITER"
    },
    "timestamp": 1646884680000,
    "value": {
        "max": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "sum": 0,
        "count": 1
    },
    "unit": "Count"
}
```

Record 2:

```
{
    "metric_stream_name": "atlas-timestamp-day-partition-parquet",
    "account_id": "123456",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "namespace": "AWS/RDS",
    "metric_name": "Aurora_pq_request_not_chosen_update_delete_stmts",
    "dimensions": {
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": "test-aurora-mysql-sandbox-reader-1"
    },
    "timestamp": 1646884680000,
    "value": {
        "max": 0,
        "min": 0,
        "sum": 0,
        "count": 1
    },
    "unit": "Count"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)` indicates that there are multiple JSON objects in the payload, which you've already noted as Record 1 and Record 2. `json.loads()` is not able to parse multiple JSON objects, hence the "extra data" error.

See this Stack Overflow post for more details: [Python json.loads shows ValueError: Extra data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058935/python-json-loads-shows-valueerror-extra-data)

An answer from the post suggests wrapping the JSON objects in an array, and then using `json.loads()` to parse the array.

```py
payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
payload_list = json.loads("[" + payload + "]")
```