# Nicely convert a .txt file to .json file

Tags: python, json

I have a `data.txt` file which I want to convert to a `data.json` file and print a nice first 2 entries (`data.txt` contains 3 unique IDs).

The `data.txt` can oublicly found [here](https://jpst.it/2WLT6) (this is a sample - original file contains 10000 unique `"linkedin_internal_id`).

I tried the following:

```py
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

data = json.dumps(content, indent=3)
```

This code doesn't print the appropriate `JSON` format of `data.txt` (it also includes `\\`). Also, my `jupyter notebook` gets stacked because of the large file size, for this, I want to nicely print only the first 2 entries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called **new line delimited** `json` where ***each line is a valid JSON value*** and ***the line separator is '\n'***, you can read it like this line by line and push it to a `list`, so later it will be easy for you to iterate/process it further. See: [ldjson](https://jsonlines.org/)

```
import json

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

data = [json.loads(item) for item in contents.strip().split('\n')]
print(data[0:2])
```

Comment: no need to str(item) here, just item should word

Comment: Thanks! I tried running your code but I have this traceback: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3575 (char 3574)`

Comment: seems issue with your large file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830719/1138192 but the file you shared earlier works fine for me while testing

Comment: Now it's working. I saved `data.txt` file as `data.json` first and then used your solution.

Comment: I added `print(json.dumps(data[:2], indent=3))` instead of `print(data[0:2])` to nicely print output.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import json
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
   data = [json.loads(f.readline()) for i in range(2)]
print(json.dumps(data))
```

This only reads and parses the first two lines of the data file, instead of loading the whole thing and then extracting the first two items.